# How achieve this layout (see picture included)?

Tags: android, layout

I'm having trouble getting a layout looking like this:

[image]

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <TextView
    android:layout_below="@id/text1/>

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignRightOf="@id/text1">

        <ImageButton/>
        <ImageButton/>
        <ImageButton/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Or more specifically, is it possible to set an layout_align on , like this: `android:layout_alignRightOf="@id/text1"`

If not, how do I get this layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how (if possible) to do it with RelativeLayout, but with some LinearLayout should be quite easy, here a sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#aa0000ff"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#aaff0000"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this is the perfect example for a `LinearLayout`. Take a look at the Linearlayouts **weight property.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ImageButton02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_plus" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_plus" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_plus" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This would also work, it's the same as lellomans, but he beat you to the finish.

Answer (score 0):

Create one parent relative layout which will have two child relative layouts
1. first child relative layout which will have left two textviews
2. Second child relative layout will have right side imageviews

Comment: Ok, but if the three imageviews should have the same height as the two textviews, as the picture, how do I achieve that?

Comment: That height will be controlled by two child relativelayouts. You should set the height same for both relative layoyts

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
  <RelativeLayout
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff4500"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="212dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:text="Large Text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:text="Large Text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:text="Large Text" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```